# Looping JSON data in Morris.js and Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, morris.js

within my Controller I do something like this

```
$responseCounts = json_encode(array_count_values($countArray));
dd($responseCounts);
```

This outputs the following

```
"{"Answer 4":6,"Answer 2":25,"Answer 3":19,"Answer 1":20}"
```

Now I am trying to use this data to create a Morris.js chart.  Within Javascript, I do

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var data = '{{ $responseCounts }}';
        data = data.replace(/&quot;/ig,'"');
        data = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

By the time I output the data to the console I see

```
Object { Answer 4=6,  Answer 2=25,  Answer 3=19,  more...}
```

Now I am on the Morris part, so far I have

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'chart',
    data: [
        { Answers: 'A', Count: 3 },
        { Answers: 'B', Count: 10 },
        { Answers: 'C', Count: 5 },
        { Answers: 'D', Count: 17 }
    ],
    xkey: 'Answers',
    ykeys: ['Count'],
    labels: ['Answers']
});
```

Obviously at the moment I am outputting fake data.  What I am trying to do now is use my data variable.  The left part of the Object represents a column on the X Axis.  The second part is the count for each column.  So I essentially want to show that Answer 1 has 20, Answer 2 has 25 etc.

How could I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for this task you actually want to use `{!! $responseCounts !!}` which is a blade specific Syntax for printing unfiltered data. So what your data variable needs to look like is:

```
var data = JSON.parse({!! $responseCounts !!});
```

The next issue is that the Object you now have contains multiple key value pairs in one object, but you need a well defined array with multiple objects having 2 key value pairs.

```
var morrisData = [];

$.each(data, function(key, val){
    morrisData.push({'Answer': key.split('Answer')[1], 'Count' : val}); 
});
```

Now you will have an object that looks like this:

```
[
    { 'Answer' : 2, 'Count' : 25 },
    { 'Answer' : 3, 'Count' : 19 }
    { 'Answer' : 4, 'Count' : 6 }
]
```

And so on...

Then you can simply invoke `Morris`and pass `data:morrisData`

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'chart',
    data:morrisData,
    xkey: 'Answers',
    ykeys: ['Count'],
    labels: ['Answers']
});
```

Of course you can also mutate the object server-side with php, but I don't know how it's being constructed so I can't help there.

Comment: Thank you, that is fantastic.  One question I have, the key.split relies on the Answer starting with Answer.  If the answer is something else, it displays as undefined.  Is there a way to handle any answer?

Comment: @kate_hudson Is there a common denominator in what the `key` will be? Such as will an integer be present in that string always?

Comment: No, the answer could be anything

Comment: @kate_hudson Then that is what the index will become. You can just omit the whole split part and just do `morrisData.push({'Answer': key, 'Count': val});`